# How to save boolean properly on Playerprefs?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a shop system if I buy the items, the items will be saved on `Playerprefs`, no need to buy again when I restart or re-open the game, for that I already make it to `setInt` but I don't know when I call `getInt`. I tried to call it in the start method with a new int index but it doesn't work. This my script

for store the itemsType

```
[System.Serializable]
public class m_ShopItem 
{
    public Sprite theIcon;
    public int price;
    public bool isBuyed;
}
```

Then I make a list

```
public List<m_ShopItem> ShopItemsList = new List<m_ShopItem>();
 [SerializeField] GameObject ShopPanel;
    [SerializeField] Transform theContent;
    GameObject g;
    Button buyBtn;
    public GameObject itemTemplate;

    private void Start()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ShopItemsList.Count; i++)
        {

            g = Instantiate(itemTemplate, theContent);
            g.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = ShopItemsList[i].theIcon;
            g.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = ShopItemsList[i].price.ToString();
            buyBtn = g.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Button>();
            if (ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed)
            {
                DisableBuyButton();
            }
            ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isBuyed") == 1 ? true : false;// i call it Get here 
            Debug.Log(ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed);
            buyBtn.AddEventListener(i, OnShopItemBtnClicked);
        }
    }
    void OnShopItemBtnClicked(int itemIndex)
    {
        if (m_shopManager.Instance.HasEnoughCoins(ShopItemsList[itemIndex].price))
        {
            m_shopManager.Instance.UseCoins(ShopItemsList[itemIndex].price);
            //purchase Item
            ShopItemsList[itemIndex].isBuyed = true;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isBuyed", ShopItemsList[itemIndex].isBuyed ? 1 : 0); // SetThe Int here when button clicked and buy the item

            //disable the button
            buyBtn = theContent.GetChild(itemIndex).GetChild(2).GetComponent<Button>();
            DisableBuyButton();

            //add avatar
            m_Profile.Instance.AddBallType(ShopItemsList[itemIndex].theIcon);
        }
        else
        {
            //NoCoinsAnim.SetTrigger("NoCoins");
            Debug.Log("You don't have enough coins!!");
        }
    }

    void DisableBuyButton()
    {
        buyBtn.interactable = false;
        buyBtn.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = "PURCHASED";
    }
```

[image]

but the result is the same I have to rebuy when going to the main menu or restart the game.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my script?

Comment: You would need to call the  `ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isBuyed") == 1 ? true : false;` Before checking for the value of `ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed`

Comment: yup forget to mention it, if I checking before all item.isBuyed, all listed will be purchased @MathewHD

Answer (score 1):

Your current problem is that you create only one [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) Object with the value being equal to 1 or 0.

So if you buy only one of your shop items all of them get unlocked. Because you only Check if the [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) is `true`(1) or `false` (0).

To fix that we would need to create a List of unique [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) equal to the amount of shop items. We can do that if we add the index in the `ShopItemsList` to the `isBuyed` name.

**Create initial Playerprefs:**

```cs
// Called before the Start Function
private void Awake() {
    // Loop through all shopping Items
    for (int i = 0; i < ShopItemsList.Count; i++) {
        // Check if the Item was already bought
        bool bought = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isBuyed"+i) == 1 ? true : false;
        // If it was we can't reset the score.
        if (!bought) {
            // Create a different PlayerPrefs for each Item in the Shop.
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isBuyed"+i, ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }
}
...
```

Now we can check for that [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) instead of checking for just once in `Start()`.

**Check if Items were bought:**

```cs
private void Start() {
    // Loop through all shopping Items
    for (int i = 0; i < ShopItemsList.Count; i++) {
        ...
        // Actualize our values so already bought items can't be bought again
        ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isBuyed"+i) == 1 ? true : false;
        // Check if the item was bought
        if (ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed) {
            DisableBuyButton();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

We also need to make sure that we set the right [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) when we buy a Product from the Shop. To ensure that we can just add the `itemIndex` parameter we get from the function and add that to the `isBuyed` name.

**Buying Items:**

```cs
void OnShopItemBtnClicked(int itemIndex) {
    ...
    // Buy the Item.
    ShopItemsList[itemIndex].isBuyed = true;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isBuyed"+itemIndex, ShopItemsList[itemIndex].isBuyed ? 1 : 0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: so when I click to buy `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isBuyed", ShopItemsList[itemIndex].isBuyed ? 1 : 0);` be `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isBuyed"+ ItemIndex,ShopItemsList[itemIndex].isBuyed ? 1 : 0);`too right ?

Comment: Yeah exactly I'll add some more text to explain that as well.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still the same not saved, maybe because Create the initial PlayerPrefs on the awake so it will reset if restart the game.

Comment: Yeah sry `Awake` is just a function that will be called before `Start`. So you need to add a check if it was already set as well. I edited my answer to include that as well.